# Archiving an SQL table of sessions and statistics

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, join

**What my query is doing:**

I have two SQL tables and I want to copy datarows from the one table to the other table. I am doing this for statistics. The source table includes all current member-sessions/logins and with my statistics table I also want to see member-logins of the past. Thus I want to store these data into my bot_sessions_statistics table as well to make sure they are not being updated anymore:

**The original query:**

```
INSERT INTO bot_sessions_statistics (member_id, session_token, username, ip_address)
SELECT sessions.member_id, sessions.session_token, sessions.username, sessions.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions AS sessions
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT stats.member_id, stats.session_token, stats.username, stats.ip_address
    FROM bot_sessions_statistics as stats
    WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
) AS stats
ON sessions.member_id = stats.member_id
WHERE latest_renewal >= date(NOW())
AND stats.member_id IS NULL
```

**The performance of the original query:**

```
Query_time: 86.364613  Lock_time: 0.000085 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1088312551
```

**The table structures:**

Table bot_sessions: [image: bot_sessions table definition]

Table bot_sessions_statistics: [image: bot_sessions_statistics table definition]

**The performance of single queries:**

```
SELECT sessions.member_id, sessions.session_token, sessions.username, sessions.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions AS sessions
WHERE latest_renewal >= date(NOW())
```

Returns 44.2k rows (Duration: 0.078s / Fetch: 1.607s)

```
SELECT stats.member_id, stats.session_token, stats.username, stats.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions_statistics as stats
WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
```

Returns 23.3k rows (Duration: 0.047s / Fetch 0.920s)

Answer (score 2):

I have much more experience with SQL Server than with MySQL, but I think that some things very similar:

1. **`LEFT JOIN` replacement** - you are using only `member_id` from stats inner query. You could just have a direct `LEFT JOIN` with the `bot_sessions_statistics` table.
2. **[Cluster index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) candidate** - `bot_sessions_statistics.date_active` looks like it is assigned one time with current time. As time always goes up, it should not create re-orderings. This is particularly useful when fetching multiple columns (index has all the columns) with conditions like `>= date(NOW())` (faster seeks).
3. **Possible use of [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)** - I have never used this in MySQL, but this functionality can provide increased performance when seeking data in very large tables. Partitioning by date columns might gain you some performance.
4. **`NOT EXISTS` instead of `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`** - generally, it [seems](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/) that `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` is slower that `NOT EXISTS`.